# MS SQL: Table Calculation for each Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the "balance" for a customer in my db.

```
Customer Table
-----------------
1 - Frank
2 - Bob

Invoice Table
---------------------------------------------------
id | customer_id | amount_due | credit_due
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | $10        | 
---------------------------------------------------
2  | 1           |            | $6
---------------------------------------------------
```

Here's a typical sql statement for looking up a customers info.

```
SELECT id, name FROM CUSTOMER WHERE id = ?
```

If I want to also retrieve the balance, I'm doing this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM 
(SELECT id, name FROM CUSTOMER WHERE id = ?) AS a, 
(SELECT SUM(amount_due - credit_due) AS balance FROM INVOICE WHERE cus_id = ?) AS b
```

Running this result:

```
--------------------
id | name | balance 
---------------------
1 | Frank | $4
```

This works great when retrieving just one customer, but what if I want to do a more general search? Like loading ALL customers?

This is the output I would like to get

```
--------------------
id | name | balance 
---------------------
1 | Frank | $4
---------------------
2 | Bob   | $0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use aggregation, I think:

```
select c.customer_id, c.name,
       ( coalesce(sum(i.amount_due), 0) - coalesce(sum(i.credit_due), 0) ) as balance
from customer c join
     invoice i
     on i.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id, c.name;
```

I should note that if the amount fields are `NULL`, then the expression `sum(amount_due - credit_due)` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a left join?

Comment: In my "actual" code I'm using a ISNULL() to catch null sums and just return $0

Comment: you should also `coalesce` `i.amount_due`.. not the `sum`... `sum(coalesce(i.amount_due, 0))`  same with `credit_due`